# Is it possible to send a window handle with WM_COPYDATA?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ipc, wm-copydata

I am trying to send an HWND with the WM_COPYDATA IPC method.
So far when sending a string LPCTSTR it works.

```
LPCTSTR str = L"Test";
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 20;
cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * wcslen(str);
cds.lpData = (PVOID)str;
LRESULT l = SendMessage(myhWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)nullptr, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

But when using the HWND the message doesn't even arrive...

```
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 20;
cds.cbData = sizeof(HWND);
cds.lpData = (PVOID)targetWnd;
LRESULT l = SendMessage(myhWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)nullptr, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

A PVOID should be able to point at anything afaik.

My HWNDs are both set and both of the methods above return 0 as LRESULT.
How do I debug this? Or is there something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Unless you're sending other data as well `WM_COPYDATA` is overkill to send a HWND; you can just send this as the `wParam` or `lParam` parameter of any custom message.

Comment: I don't know any other type of IPC except WM_COPYDATA for small things like syncing statuses and some vars. If there is a better method I would love to learn it.@JonathanPotter

Comment: Oh the WM_USER+x thing. Alright. But why is this overkill? Isn't that the same?

Comment: No. Sending a custom message doesn't have the system marshal memory across processes (like `WM_COPYDATA`). `SendMessage(target, MY_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)hwnd)` will simply copy the `wParam` and `lParam` values over. Though you don't want `WM_USER` messages. Use `WM_APP` messages instead, or registered messages if you want to make the message part of the public API.

Comment: "*So far when sending a string LPCTSTR it works*" - actually, it doesn't, because you are setting `cds.cbData` to the wrong value. You would need to set it to `lstrlen(str) * sizeof(*str)` instead of `sizeof(LPCTSTR)`.

Comment: The last variant I was working on was the HWND one. So recreating an example snippet quickly with the LPCTSTR got me wrong. I updated the question. Well paid attention @RemyLebeau

Comment: @Nur1 you can get the custom `MY_MESSAGE` safely using `RegisterWindowMessage` API.

Comment: @sid Defining a custom message in the `WM_APP + x` range is safe. `RegisterWindowMessage` doesn't add safety. It allows to establish a protocol that clients that aren't under your control can follow. It's rare that you need that.

Comment: @IInspectable what happens in case of collision? Like another app uses the same number to share their messages? App A using WM_APP + 1 and App B also using WMP_APP + 1?

Comment: @sid If App A and App B both handle `WM_APP + 1`, and they aren't communicating with each other, nothing will happen. If they are communicating with each other, and they agree on the semantics of the message parameters, everything still works just fine. However, if they do not agree on how to interpret the parameters, things start to fall apart. If, for example, App A sends an integer value through `lParam`, but App B interprets that as a pointer, then App B will eventually read from or write to random memory. That's hardly desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `HWND` is not a pointer.  You most likely want:

```
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 20;
cds.cbData = sizeof(HWND);
cds.lpData = &targetWnd;
//           ^
LRESULT l = SendMessage(myhWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)nullptr, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

Also, there seems to be some confusion between the source and destination `HWND`s, but perhaps that's just the way you named them.

As Jonathan Potter (and some of the other commenters) point out, there are more efficient ways of sending an `HWND`, if that's all you want to do.

Comment: Should be fine to send the value of the hwnd