# Empty String when sending a String value using WM_COPYDATA in JNA

Tags: java, c++, winapi, jna, sendmessage

I am trying to send a String from Java (First app) to c++ (the Second app with a message-only window).

So firstly, what I tried is this:
I adapted [this example](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32WindowMessagesTest.java) into my code and got this on the java side

```
    STRMSG msg = new STRMSG();
    msg.message = "test";
    //msg.write(); // Idk exactly why because i thought JNA does this before every call. Works the same without

    cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
    cds.dwData = new ULONG_PTR(UniqueWindowMessageID);
    cds.cbData = msg.size();
    cds.lpData = msg.getPointer();
    cds.write(); // But here it is somehow needed because otherwise the message will not arrive.

    JNA.USER32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(
        msgOnlyWnd, WinUser.WM_COPYDATA,
        null,
        new LPARAM(Pointer.nativeValue(cds.getPointer()))
    );
```

Oh, and `STRMSG` looks like this (also adapted from the example):

```
public class STRMSG extends Structure {

    public STRMSG() {
        super();
    }

    public STRMSG(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }

    public String message;

    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("message");
    }
}
```

On the c++ side, I got my message-only window, and I can catch the WM_COPYDATA message successfully.

But somehow, my String value is empty here:

```
    case WM_COPYDATA: {
        PCOPYDATASTRUCT cds = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;
        if (cds->dwData == UniqueWindowMessageID) { // <- works 
            STRMSG* msgStruct = (STRMSG*)cds->lpData; // <- The message struct is corrupt i guess

            cout << msgStruct->message << endl; // Will just endl in the console
        }
        break;
    }
```

This is the struct on the c++ side:

```
const struct STRMSG {
    string message;
};
```

Besides this attempt, I also tried to adapt my struct so it contains a BYTE* (byte[]) and the size so I can create a String out of the bytes and the size using this: ([source](https://www.java-forum.org/thema/jna-cpp-dll-string-verwendung.188995/))

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(inputParam), lengthParam);
```

But my struct isn't that what it should be in any way. So the data is somehow faulty, and IDK what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I also looked at the data while debugging. I didn't get anything:

[image]

EDIT2:

After the comment Remy my COPYDATASTRUCT looks like this:

```
    byte[] msg = "test".getBytes();
    cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
    cds.dwData = new ULONG_PTR(UniqueWindowMessageID);
    cds.cbData = msg.length;
    cds.lpData = msg // how??
    cds.write();
```

But how should I map the `cds.lpData` to the `byte[]`?

Comment: We already covered this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68696561/65863). Your Java code is making the same mistake your C++ code was making. You are sending only the `STRMSG` struct, but not the string data it points to. And now you are compounding the problem because the Java code is sending Java's `string` type which is not compatible with C++'s `std::string` type. There is no reason to have the `STRMSG` struct in this code at all, so get rid of it. Have the Java code encode the `string` to a `byte[]` array and then `WM_COPYDATA` can send those bytes to C++

Comment: Oh my god... your're right. Will try. I was blinded by the examples of JNA.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok so basically after removing the Structs completely. How do I map the `cds.lpData` (which is a `Pointer`) to the `byte[]`? (I also updated the question)

Comment: [Converting String to Pointer for JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158582/)

Comment: With regard to your comment questions: JNA does auto-write Structures when they are passed as arguments to native methods.  But you never pass that. So you are allocating native memory for `STRMSG` and obtaining a pointer to it, but never writing your String to it.  Which you would have lost the allocation to anyway, so it wouldn't work even with the write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, basically, after the help of `Remy Lebeau` (as always), I managed to include the `NativeString` `Class` in my project, which allows me to get the `Pointer` of the `NativeString` and use it directly in my `COPYDATASTRUCT`.

I had to `inline` some method contents in my own `NativeString` `Class` because some of them were also not visible.

Anyway, here is the snippet I used to build my `COPYDATASTRUCT` the sending part didn't change.

```
NativeString ns = new NativeString("Hello String", true); //true so its a wide string
cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
cds.dwData = new ULONG_PTR(UniqueWindowMessageID);
cds.cbData = ns.length()*2; //Without *2 the text will be only the half
cds.lpData = ns.getPointer();
cds.write();
```

And this is how I handle the received WM_COPYDATA message on the C++ side:

```
case WM_COPYDATA: {
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT cds = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;
    if (cds->dwData == UniqueWindowMessageID) {
        wchar_t* msg = (wchar_t*)cds->lpData;
        wcout << msg << endl;
    }
    break;
}
```

Thanks again @Remy Lebeau